# How to bind mousemove scroll and resize all into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I "do stuff" when the mouse moves. However, I also want to do the exact same thing if the user resizes the browser or scrolls down the browser.
    jQuery(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){ 
            var x, y;
            x = e.pageX; // x coord
            y = e.pageY; // y coord
            //other stuff
    });

I tried putting doing

```
jQuery(document).bind('mousemove resize scroll',function(e){...
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
jQuery(document, window).bind('mousemove resize scroll',function(e){...
```

but it also didn't work.

I also know that you can detect scroll using

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

and detect resize using

```
$(window).resize(function() {
```

But the if I use those detections, I won't have the "e" argument to get the x and y coordinates of the mouse

How do I bind all 3 events all into one function?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the code (tried in Google Chrome): 

`jQuery(document, window).bind('mousemove resize scroll',function(e){console.log(e)});`

and it worked for me (i acn see in console as pageX, pageY and much more). Which browser do you use?

Comment: @true the problem is that e.pageX is undefined when the resize or scroll event is activated and that is breaking my application. I need it so if there is a resize or scroll, it will call the bind mousemove and get the "e" argument from that call. I am using chrome as well. If you log e.pageX, whenever you scroll or resize, it will log "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do still have the event data in the scroll and resize methods. Try wrapping your code into a single function with 3 handlers. The on() method requires jQuery 1.7+

```
function reusable(eData){
    // Heres what you want to do every time
}
$(document).on({
    mousemove: function(e) { reusable(e); },
    scroll   : function(e) { reusable(e); }
);
$(window).on({
    resize   : function(e) { reusable(e); }
});
```

---

*edited*

The events should be in their correct objects `window` and `document` or you will get unexpected values.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'on'" and I am using jquery version 1.7.1(http://ajax.Microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)

Comment: Try using `$('body').on()` I'm not sure if it will work with window according to some of the jQuery bug tracking pages.

Comment: this will get the same problem, as he's wonder why there is no property `e.screenX` for example in the `scroll` event object.

Answer (score 1):

from your comment:

> the problem is that e.pageX is undefined when the resize or scroll event is activated and that is breaking my application

So why are you using the current object properties when you know they are `undefined`? Why not use a global variable and hold in them the last value?

> [Live example in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ugigak/5/edit#javascript)

```
var clientX = 0, clientY = 0,
    screenX = 0, screenY = 0,
    pageX = 0,   pageY = 0;    

// bind the events in the correct objects
jQuery(window).bind('resize',function(e) { getBindingValues(e); });
jQuery(document).bind('mousemove scroll',function(e) { getBindingValues(e); });

// your one-function
function getBindingValues(e) {

  clientX = e.clientX ? e.clientX : clientX;
  clientY = e.clientY ? e.clientY : clientY;

  screenX = e.screenX ? e.screenX : screenX;
  screenY = e.screenY ? e.screenY : screenY;

  pageX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : pageX;
  pageY = e.pageY ? e.pageY : pageY;

  $("#hello").html(    
    "*** Safe values ***<br/>" + 
    "mouse: X." + clientX + " Y." + clientY + "<br/>" +
    "page: X." + pageX + " Y." + pageY + "<br/>" +
    "screen: X." + screenX + " Y." + screenY + "<br/><br/>" +
    "*** More values ***<br/>" + 
    "window: W." + $(window).width() + " H." + $(window).height() + "<br/>" +
    "type: <b>" + e.type + "</b>"
  );
}
```

---

you can compare below the `e` (event) object on `mousemove` and `scroll`

*on scroll*

[image]

*on mousemove*

[image]

Comment: The event data seems to be undefined on scroll.

Comment: only some properties, just open the inspector and see for yourself. Because they are `undefined` I hold them in a global variable, so your app don't break... as you have said in the comment.

Comment: @BobRen sure I do, `resize` is an event from the `window` object, not the `document` as you specify... it should be `$(window).bind('resize', ...`

Comment: Is there any way I can use that elegantly so that I don't have to use repetitive code?

Comment: just change `document` to `window`, the resize and scroll bubble up to window. Changed my example and answer code accordingly.

Comment: But, then the x and y coordinates don't change when you scroll because it is relative to the window instead of the document. I need the x and y coordinates relative to the entire document.

Comment: then you need to put you method outside and call it, just like James Hay mentioned, he just add all to the `window` event. Answer updated with new code.