# Why is mousemove not firing when scrollbar is dragged in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does anybody know how to fix this or to find an alternate solution?

Thanks in advance.

Here is a simple example

**html**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#parent { width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll }
#child { width: 1000px; height: 10px;}
```

**js**

```
window.onmousemove = function(e)  {
    console.log(e.pageX);
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code for us to analyze?

Comment: Works just fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4xUvS/)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev actually, it doesn't seem to work. I have amended your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xUvS/1/) slightly to show the mouse position at all times. When you click and drag the scrollbar in Chrome, the pos value doesn't change. If you do the same in Firefox, it does. Weird issue, I can't find a workaround sadly.

Comment: @SimonAdcock ahh... I did not quite understand the issue. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591741/how-to-bind-mousemove-scroll-and-resize-all-into-one-function

Comment: thanks, but this will not work for my problem. in my issue the scrollable div will be removed and appended during the scrollbar is moved (why is irrlevant). after i've appended the div element i have to replace the regular scroll functionality with the mousemove event, because the scrollbar is no more dragged by mouse and can't be moved anymore. (it shouldn't be necessary to drag the scrollbar a second time.. the user must not notice that the element is removed and appended). i hope you can understand my problem, my english is not the best..sry