# Get mouse position over scrollbar in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, scroll, mouseover

I need to detect when the cursor is hovering over the scrollbar. I'm using Chrome and jQuery. This works in Firefox but not in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/HQrrq/1/

The essence is:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(mouseMoveEvent){
        console.log(mouseMoveEvent.pageY);
});
```

So, simple question: how to I get the mouse position when hovering over the document scrollbar in Chrome?

Comment: Looks like there is a similar question but it doesn't have an answer either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931620/why-is-mousemove-not-firing-when-scrollbar-is-dragged-in-google-chrome  It appears that `mousemove` events are simply not fired over scrollbars in Chrome.

Comment: I hoped being more specific in what I want (pageY) and the two-year progress may have introduced some new way of tackling this issue. I did upvote that question before making mine (fishing with dynamite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed roasted's answer basic idea, but the idea of adding calculation to page height and width on every page with did not appeal to me. I implemented a CSS solution instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/HQrrq/8/

The idea is to make html and body 100% width and height, and add a div as body's first child. This will be the same as 'body' for all intents and purposes, and is just a patch to let Google Chrome know that the scrollbars are actually part of the document.

CSS:

```
html, body, #bodyContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#bodyContainer {
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ya, its really better than my answer! Thx for sharing it! BTW, don't forget to accept it, could really help other users ;)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it creates a horizontal scrollbar on the document.

Comment: @MartynChamberlin it doesn't - but it  seems to be the case that the CSS on my fiddle didn't include the margin:0 and padding:0 for body, which is most likely why it happened. I've updated my answer with a fiddle that actually includes my answer's CSS, better results?

Comment: And note that <div id="loremContainer" style="height: 50px; width: 200%;"> is on purpose, otherwise it would be hard to check whether the solution works or not ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could be a kind of workaround:  {looks like need to handle some window resize too!}

http://jsfiddle.net/HQrrq/3/

```
var loremContainer = $('#loremContainer')[0],
    scrollbarWidth = loremContainer.offsetWidth - loremContainer.clientWidth,
    scrollbarHeight = loremContainer.offsetHeight - loremContainer.clientHeight;

$('#loremContainer').height($(window).height() - scrollbarHeight).width($(window).width() - scrollbarWidth);
```

Comment: That's pretty amazing! The container scrollbars are part of the document while the body's scrollbars are not!

Comment: Thanks for the basic solution. I used some CSS to reach the same goal, and posted it in a different answer.